# Change color of item being dropped in list after item is dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to change color of the item after it dragged and dropped into droppable field. How it can be done? Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/bbthwfr2/) i have. So as I said i want to color of dropped item to be changed when its dropped. And javascript code:

```
$(function() {
  var x = $(".addtofavs li").length;
  var y = $(".addtoquicklinks li").length;
  $("#atf-count").text(x);
  $("#atq-count").text(y);
  $("#catalog ").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
  });
  $("#myAccordion li").draggable({
    connectToSortable: '.container',
    helper: 'clone',
    revertDuration: 0,
    create: function() {
      var eq = $(this).index();
      $(this).attr('data-index', eq);
    }
  });

  $(".container").sortable({
    connectWith: '.container',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      var uiIndex = ui.item.attr('data-index');
      var item = $(this).find('[data-index=' + uiIndex + ']');
      if (item.length > 1) {
        item.last().remove();
      }
    },
    revert: true
  });

  $(".container li").draggable({
    connectToSortable: '.container',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    revert: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you want to change color of li that is dropped in favorite container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element that is drop to your container on receive event of sortable by ui.item  and the change color for it.

Try this

```
$(".container").sortable({
        connectWith: '.container',
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        receive: function(event, ui) {
          var uiIndex = ui.item.attr('data-index');
          var item = $(this).find('[data-index=' + uiIndex + ']');
          if (item.length > 1) {
            item.last().remove();
          }
          $(ui.item).css("background", "red");
        },
        revert: true
      });
```

Here is working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cqLv5n64/2/

Answer (score 1):

A little tricky, as `ui.item` in the `receive: function(event, ui)` part of your `.sortable` references the **original** element, as opposed to the dropped element.

However if you modify your sortable as follows:

```
$(".container").sortable({
    connectWith: '.container',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) { draggedItem = ui.item;},
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      draggedItem.css("background", "blue");
```

(Adding the `beforeStop` attribute) then you can access draggedItem (which references the dragged/dropped **new** element).

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bbthwfr2/2/

**Edit:**
Changing the colour of the **original** element is much simpler:

```
receive: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.css("background", "blue");
```

(`beforeStop` isn't required).

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bbthwfr2/3/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i think you didnt get my question, I want to change color of item in my accordion after its dropped in favorites section. Means after, for example, "lolcat shirt" is dropped into favorites, color of "lolcat shirt" inside accordion should be changed, not inside favorites box.